# как сделать ссылку с двумя параметрами?

Tags: php

Вопрос такой как сделать что бы в одной ссылке передавалось 2 get параметра

```html
<a href='https://*****/clients/showClient.php?val=".$my["id"]."?id=".$_GET["id"]."'>
```

Comment: неужели сложно хотя бы [википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#GET) открыть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй и последующие ? замените на  &

Answer (score 1):

Вместо второго вопросика поставьте знак `&`

```
<a href='https://*****/clients/showClient.php?val=".$my["id"]."&id=".$_GET["id"]."'>
```

Comment: спасибо я пробовал так  /clients/showClient.php?val=".$my["id"]."?&id=".$_GET["id"]."'> у вас все работает

Comment: & нужно поставить вместо вопроса, а не за ним.

Comment: это я понял просто не знал